# Passing multiple variables in a jekyll include and detecting which ones are assigned

Tags: variables, include, jekyll

In a jekyll website, I'm trying to use an **include** as a multi-purpose template by passing multiple variables; not always all of them, not always the same number of variables.

From the page, I want to do this:

```
{% include multi-purpose.html var1='foo' var2='ble' var3='yea' %}
```

When I do this in the **include.html**, and when var1 *has* a value, it works:

```
var1 is {{ include.var1 }}
```

In the **include** file I want to be able to discriminate which variables are assigned, by doing something like this:

```
{% if var1 != null %}
    this is my var1 {{ include.var1 }}
{% endif %}

{% if var2 != null %}
    this is my var2 {{ include.var2 }}
{% endif %}

{% if var3 != null %}
    this is my var3 {{ include.var3 }}
{% endif %}

etc...
```

Unfortunately, my syntax is wrong, this code doesn't render the code inside the if statements.

I also tried this:

```
{% if var1 != '' %}
    this is my var1 {{ include.var1 }}
{% endif %}

{% if var2 != '' %}
    this is my var2 {{ include.var2 }}
{% endif %}

{% if var3 != '' %}
    this is my var3 {{ include.var3 }}
{% endif %}

etc...
```

This one renders everything, regardless it is assigned or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the passed variables from inside the include, you need to prefix them with `include.`
**Everywhere** in the include!

Change this:

```
{% if var1 != null %}
```

to this:

```
{% if include.var1 != null %}
```

---

`{% if var1 ...` doesn't work because it checks for a "local" variable (declared **inside** the include) named `var1` *(which doesn't exist, of course)*.

As explained in Mitja's answer, you don't need to check for `null` or `''`, but you would still need to check `{% if include.var1 %}`, not `{% if var1 %}`!

Answer (score 1):

Just check like this:

```
{% if var1 %}
```

Comment: liquid doc about types is here http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/types

Comment: as explained further, you need to scope it down to **include.var1**

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I forgot the include. Was just looking at your if statements and corrected that.